# Determining the values of Boolean variables

Tags: python, numpy

Consider two Boolean variables, A and B, and some logical operation(s) on these variables, resulting in C:

```
C = A [OP] B
```

where 'OP' could be any combination of '&', '|', '^', '~', etc.

The values of A and B are to be determined.

Is it possible to create *a series of tests* using logical operations to definitively determine the True/False value of A and B based solely on the value of C for each test?

Since the application is being developed using NumPy, I am most interested in operators found natively in this package.

Comment: Do you know C and the operator? I don't see how you could determine A and B based just on C. For example if C is True, the right hand side could be A or B, A and B, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you can't *definitely* determine A and B if you're simply given the value of C and the operation used.

A single counter-example is needed to disprove it:

```
C= True
OP= |
```

There's three possible valid states for A and B: `A=True, B=True`, `A=True, B=False`, `A=False, B=True`

---

For multiple (user-chosen) tests, we get the same result, if you restrict yourself to `&`,`|` and `^` (xor). It's clearly not possible in the general case - since the operations are commutative, you can't tell apart A and B.

As an example, if

```
A & B == False
A | B == True
A ^ B == True
```

both `A=True, B=False` and `A=False, B=True` satisfy the conditions.

---

If we don't apply any restriction *at all* on the expressions you can test, getting the values of `B` (for example) is trivial: just evaluate `C=(A|~A)|B` and the result will be equal to `B`

But then, if you don't have *any* restriction, you could just say `C=B` and test it directly!

Comment: It is possible, though, given *enough* pairs of C/op. For instance, True/| and False/^ would provide enough information to know that both A and B were true.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am after: a *series* of tests.

Comment: @cytochrome is there any restriction on the tests you want to make? Can you use any number of logical operators in a single test?

Comment: Aso, if you can write any test you want, why not simply test the value of `A` and `B` directly? I think you need to specify more precisely what are the restrictions here. Meanwhile, I've updated the question to deal with `&`,`|` and `^`

Comment: @chepner it's possible in your particular example, but not in a general sense (for commutative operations). I've added a counter-example in the answer

Comment: That's not a counterexample; it simply doesn't have enough pairs. Adding something like ~A/True would provide enough information.

Comment: Any number of logical operators can be used in a single test. Thanks!

Comment: @chepner That's why I mentioned *commutative* operators. If you can test `~A`, why wouldn't you just test `A` directly?

Comment: Good question. I know that it sounds odd, but for this application, A and B can't be tested independently.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned ~, which I assumed was NOT. I don't know if we can assume other binary operations not listed, such as NOR, which would also allow us to provide sufficient tests to uniquely determine A and B.

Comment: @cytochrome define **independently** :) You can write an expression using both variables that allows you to calculate A and B directly (see answer edit) - but it *needs* to eliminate the effects of one variable in order to get the other

Comment: @chepner indeed, more operations (such as NOR or NAND) would provide enough information, but I don't think those are [available in python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) - unless you create them somehow

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input! I think that I have a better idea of how to proceed.

Comment: @cytochrome: if this answers your question, why don't you accept the answer?  You have 11 questions with only 2 answers accepted.